# PHP unserialize keeps throwing same error over 100 times part 2

Tags: php, serialization

So I have a large 2d array that i serialize, but when I attempt to unserialize the array it just throws the same error to the point of nearly crashing Firefox.

The error is:

```
Warning: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Node no longer exists in /var/www/dev/wc_paul/inc/analyzerTester.php on line 24
```

I would include the entire serialized array that I echo out but last time I tried that on this form it crashed my Firefox.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

I'm sure this is an array. However, it was originally an XML response from another server that I then pulled values from to build the array. If it can't be serialized I can accept that I guess... but how should I go about saving it then?

Comment: This should be merged with the old question, not posed as a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when you get an error message, you can figure out a great deal by simply searching the web for that very message.  For example, when you put [Node no longer exists](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Node+no+longer+exists) into Google, you end up with [a concise explanation of why this is happening, along with a solution](http://www.rhinocerus.net/node/16347), as the very first hit.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your second question about how else you could save the data

why not output the xml responce directly to a file and save it locally, then read from the local file when required.